# GitHub - Share - Why are there two projects and what do they mean?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Why are there two projects in this Xamarin solution, and what is the ShareExtensions?

Dos there have to be two projects?
https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ios8/Share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an example of an [iOS 8 Extension](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_extensions/).

The ShareExtension is basically a very lightweight View that you register with iOS.  It tells iOS that when the user chooses to "Share" from another App, your app is an available target.  The other App is the "host" app that will receive whatever content the user is choosing to share.  There are other flavors of extension that will either have no host app, or have a pre-determined host like the Photo editor.